# How to avoid orange buildup on shower tile grout?

Tags: shower, stain

Once a month, I have to use an old tooth brush to gently remove the orange buildup on the grout between our shower tiles. I don't have to use any solvents or chemicals. A little water is all that I use. What can I do after each shower to minimize this buildup? Using a tooth brush after each shower would be too time-consuming of course. I prefer natural remedies. For instance, would a watered-down white vinegar spray on the areas help without damaging the grout? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is this all over the shower, or just underneath the shower head?

Answer (score 1):

Orange?

Filter out the iron in your water supply.

Comment: This water is coming out of my shower head. I have never heard of a filtering system for bath areas.

Comment: Iron filtering would typically be installed where the main water supply enters the house, and it would then filter the entire water supply for everything in the house, not just a particular area.

Answer (score 0):

Your stain is bacterial. The only way to get rid of it permanently is to get rid of what it feeds on -- soap residue etc. If you're in the pacific northwest, its presence is quite possibly due to the US government doing biological weapons testing during the cold war! (This is not a conspiracy theory, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serratia_marcescens#Role_in_biowarfare_testing)

Since it's biological, a good soak and scrub with bleach is the solution.